# Unable to install Marketplace client 1.8.2 on DBeaver 21

Tags: eclipse, dbeaver, eclipse-marketplace

I Update to DBeaver 21 on Mac OSX 11.2.1.

However after installing it I tried to install the Marketplace Client 1.8.2 & got the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Marketplace Client 1.8.2.v20200309-0038 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group 1.8.2.v20200309-0038)
  Software currently installed: DBeaver 21.0.0.202102281712 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.core.product 21.0.0.202102281712)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Discovery UI 1.1.400.v20191213-1911 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery 1.1.400.v20191213-1911)
    Equinox Provisioning Discovery UI 1.2.0.v20200916-1234 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery 1.2.0.v20200916-1234)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Marketplace Client 1.8.2.v20200309-0038 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group 1.8.2.v20200309-0038)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui [1.8.2.v20200309-0038,1.8.2.v20200309-0038]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Marketplace Client 1.8.2.v20200309-0038 (org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui 1.8.2.v20200309-0038)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery [1.0.0,1.2.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2, Discovery UI support 1.2.800.v20200916-1234 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group 1.2.800.v20200916-1234)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery [1.2.0.v20200916-1234,1.2.0.v20200916-1234]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: DBeaver Community Edition 21.0.0.202102281712 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.ce.feature.feature.group 21.0.0.202102281712)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.jkiss.dbeaver.standalone.feature.feature.group [21.0.0.202102281712,21.0.0.202102281712]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: DBeaver 21.0.0.202102281712 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.core.product 21.0.0.202102281712)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.jkiss.dbeaver.ce.feature.feature.group [21.0.0.202102281712,21.0.0.202102281712]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: DBeaver Standalone 21.0.0.202102281712 (org.jkiss.dbeaver.standalone.feature.feature.group 21.0.0.202102281712)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery.feature.feature.group [1.2.800.v20200916-1234,1.2.800.v20200916-1234]
```

I downgraded to previous versions of DBeaver but unfortunatley get the same error.

It was also suggested that I run it from the command line as root so that it has correct permissions to save the files for the plugin install, but it still failed to install.

Comment: Why do you want to install an outdated version of the Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC)? Why not MPC 1.9.0 (update site: [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest))?

Comment: Thanks @howlger I didnt know I was installing an older version. The new version installs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @howgler for the answer. I also found the answer on DBeaver issues page on github.
So the resolution is as follows.

Add the http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/releases/1.9.0 as source and then install the marketplace client from there.